# Spacemacs Org Mode: Targets not appearing in refile

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

I have a org file I want to refile stuff into:

```
* Projects
** GWAS and Wheat
*** Tasks
**** TODO Install Data on IPlant platform
**** TODO Collect Data from system or other journals
**** TODO Install Software on IPlant platform
**** TODO Get set up on IPlant platform
SCHEDULED: <2016-01-25 Mon>

*** Notes
** Mouse and Hybridisation
*** Tasks
*** Notes
* Meetings
* General Notes
* Someday
```

I have an in-file with an example task I want to refile. I want to refile it under:

```
** Mouse and Hybridisation
*** Tasks
```

This is the task:

```
* Tasks
** TODO Figure out conversion from hal and maf to varant formats. 
SCHEDULED: <2016-01-25 Mon>
```

I have the following in my .spacemacs file after reading how to configure refiles on Google.

```
;; Set the refile targets for refiling.
    (setq org-refile-targets
          '((nil :level . 2)
            (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 9)))
```

org-agenda-files is basically set to the folder, which in which my first file I want to refile stuff into is stored.

So - I put my cursor on the task I want to refile. Do C-c C-w, and the tree of targets comes up, and I can select everything in the file, *except* The **Mouse and Hybridisation** stuff.

i.e. my options are:

```
* Projects
** GWAS and Wheat
*** Tasks
**** TODO Install Data on IPlant platform
**** TODO Collect Data from system or other journals
**** TODO Install Software on IPlant platform
**** TODO Get set up on IPlant platform
*** Notes
* Meetings
* General Notes
* Someday
```

Why would it exclude Mouse and Hybridisation section, even when I put the max levels up to 9, and why is it happy for GWAS and Wheat to be viable options when it's the same level?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: I think I'm getting further. If I swap the order of `** GWAS and Wheat` and `** Mouse and Hybridisation` Then the `** Mouse and Hybridisation` subheadings of `** Tasks` and `** Notes` are valid options for refile, but the same subheadings for `** GWAS and Wheat` are no longer presented as options. Therefore I am now questioning whether it's something to do with the fact both `** Mouse and Hybridisation` and `** GWAS and Wheat` have identical subheading names?